# クロス表で集計軸(columns)を水平方向に複数並べる方法。

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

【質問文修正】
「stock_a」と１つの変数を軸にした集計表の出力はできましたが、
例えば「stock_a」「industry_a」等、複数の変数を同じレベルで並べた集計表の出力ができません。どのようなコードが適切でしょうか。

### コード

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id':['id00001','id00002','id00003','id00004','id00005','id00006','id00007','id00008','id00009','id00010'],
'size_a':[1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,2,2],
'stock_a':[2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
'industry_a':[2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1]
})
print(df)

print(pd.crosstab(index=df['size_a'],columns=df['stock_a']))
```

### 出力結果

#### 現在の結果

```
stock_a   1   2
size_a         
1         3  49
2         5  21
3        13   6
```

#### 出力したい結果

```
stock_a   1   2  industry_a   1   2
size_a           size_a
1         3  49  1           23  29
2         5  21  2           12  14
3        13   6  3            8  11
```

Comment: 「集計軸1」と「集計軸2」の元々のデータがどんなものかをcsvかDataFrameを初期化するコードで、それから「Base:」と「全体」の欄はどう絡む(作られる/元からある)のか、といったことをテキストで追記してください。またこんな記事が参考になるのでは？[Pandasユーザーガイド「mergeとjoinとconcatenateとcompare」（公式ドキュメント日本語訳）](https://qiita.com/nkay/items/aea83237d7e388e79cd7)

Comment: 元データのサンプルとなるcsv等がないとデータ構造が分かりませんね。やりたいことはマルチカラム（マルチインデックス）でしょうか？

Comment: @kunif
CSVのデータをキャプチャして画像アップしました。
「全体」の136サンプルですが、こちらは全体のサンプル数(データ数)です。
「Base:」ですが、集計ベースになります。
全体の136サンプルの中で、A(stock=1)に該当するサンプルが31サンプル
B(stock=2)とC(stock=3)になっています。
記事を拝見しました。ご共有ありがとうございます。

Comment: @merino 
分かりづらく恐縮です。マルチカラムではなく変数は１つです。

Comment: @Hidenori さん、質問記事に貴方が注目している点だけ書かれても、他の人にはその背景・前後関係とか細かいことが分からないし、検証・調査が出来なかったり手間がかかるので、答えにくくなります。これらのヘルプ記事 [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を参考に質問内容を整理・追記してください。

Comment: @kunif さん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
DataFrameでデータ構造を記載しました。
更新しましたのでご連絡だけさせてください。
今回初めての投稿でしたが、以後気を付けます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もっとスマートな方法があると思いますが、こんな感じでステップを踏んでいけば出来ます。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id':['id00001','id00002','id00003','id00004','id00005','id00006','id00007','id00008','id00009','id00010'],
'size_a':[1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,2,2],
'stock_a':[2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
'industry_a':[2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1]
})
print(df)

df1 = pd.crosstab(index=df['size_a'],columns=df['stock_a']).reset_index()
print(df1)

df2 = pd.crosstab(index=df['size_a'],columns=df['industry_a']).reset_index()
print(df2)

resultdf = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, sort=False, join='outer', keys=['stock_a','industry_a'], names=['',''])
print(resultdf)
```

最後の結果はこうなります。

```
  stock_a       industry_a
   size_a  1  2     size_a  1  2
0       1  1  4          1  1  4
1       2  0  3          2  2  1
2       3  0  2          3  1  1
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！自身の環境でも再現できました。
concat関数を使うのですね。頂いたコードで早速進めてみます。